# aligning an image horizontally to the right of text in CSS within a larger Div

Tags: html, css, image, alignment

I need images for the Top , Middle and Bottom to be on the right hand side of the text within these divs. at the moment even though the images go right and text left the image sits below the paragraphs position. I have applyed a reset.css already as well.

Here is the relevent HTML and CSS

Index.html extract:

```
<Div id="background">

    <div id="Space">
    </div><!--spacing between divs-->

<article id="Top">
    <h2>Flower arrangement</h2>
        <p>Our team of professional designers will make your event memorable and stress free. We will design to your theme, colour, budget and needs with attention to detail given high priority.</p>
        <img src="Images/Top_Image.gif" alt="" width="207" height="195">
        <a href="#" >Read More </a>     
</article>

    <div id="Top_box">
    </div><!--spacing between divs-->

<article id="Middle">
    <h2>Seed Library</h2>
        <p>Don't be afraid to try growing your own plants, you will be surprised how easy seed germination really is. A large variety of native seed mixes are offered, ideal for creating sustainable wildflower gardens.</p>
        <a href="#" >Read More </a>
        <img src="Images/Middle_picture.gif" alt="" width="208" height="216">

</article>

    <div id="Middle_box">
    </div><!--spacing between divs-->

<article id="Review">
    <h2>Ran Dome said:</h2>
        <p>'I have never had such an outstanding experience with such a wonderful group of people who understood my needs'</p>
        <img src="Images/Review_picture.gif" alt="" width="93" height="120">

</article>

<div id="Review_box">
</div><!--spacing between divs-->

<article id="Bottom">
    <h2>Sustainability</h2>
        <p>Belinda Aspect founded Aspect in April 1985 and is a leading expert on green floral design. Belinda's dual passions for floral design and sustainability were merged when she decided that The Aspect would 'go green'.</p>
        <a href="#" >Read More </a>
        <img src="Images/Bottom_picture.gif" alt="" width="208" height="216">
</article>

<div id="Bottom_box">
</div><!--spacing between divs-->

</Div><!--background picture Div-->
```

style.css extract:

```
#background {
    background-image: url(Images/background.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width:100%;
}
#catch_line{
    color: #7f6e99;
    height: 50%px;
    width: 57%;
    margin-left: 6%;
    margin-top:132px;
    background-color: #000000;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#catch_line h1{
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-size: 3.4em;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    paddingtop: 50px;
    color: #7f6e99;
}
article#Top, article#Review {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #7a9c52;
}
article#Middle, article#Bottom {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #2d6d18;
}
article#Top h2, article#Middle h2, article#Bottom h2 {
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    color: #0c1306;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
    word-spacing: 2px;
    padding-top: 3%;
    padding-left: 6%;
    margin right: 0px;
}
article#Top p, article#Middle p, article#Bottom p{
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #0c1306;
    width: 70%;
    clear: none;
    display:block;
    padding-left: 6%;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
    margin right: 0px;
}
article#Top a, article#Middle a, article#Bottom a {
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    color: #dc3646;
    text-decoration: none;
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 6%;
    margin right: 0px;
}
article#Top img, article#Middle img, article#Bottom img{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
    clear: none;
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;
    display:block;
    margin left: 0px;
}
article#Review h2 {
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    color: #0c1306;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
    word-spacing: 2px;
    padding-top: 2.5%;
    text-align: center;
 }
article#Review p {
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #0c1306;
    text-align:center;
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-right: 10%;
    padding-bottom: 0.5%;
}
article#Review img{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display:block;
    height: 78px;
    width:62px;
}
#Space, #Top_box, #Middle_box, #Review_box, #Bottom_box{
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    height: 80px;
    clear: both;
}
```

I am also aware that I could change it so that the articles have margins instead and get rid of the spacing divs to get the same effect as what I want from them but I'm not concerned with that at the moment.

Comment: First of all I would fix your code:

- `height: 50%px;` is wrong
- You have the anchor tag in different positions: one time before the image another time after that. Is that intended?

That said, since your image seems to have a fixed height, you might apply a `margin-top: -70px`. Also post your example on jsbin et al so we can take a better look at it.

Comment: I did fix that up after posting this and realising and it didn't fix it, I'll try the margin-top in the morning and see if it helps, and I don't think the anchors are intentional, do you mind pointing them out to me so I can fix it?